# Execute shell command and retrieve stdout in Python

Tags: python, perl, shell

In Perl, if I want to execute a shell command such as `foo`, I'll do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$stdout = `foo`
```

In Python I found this very complex solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('foo', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
stdout = p.stdout.readlines()
retval = p.wait()
```

Is there any better solution ?

Notice that I don't want to use `call` or `os.system`. I would like to place `stdout` on a variable

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: Why not simply : `os.system("cd ..")`

Comment: OK fair enough, in which case you're up against questions like http://stackoverflow.com/q/89228/2088135

Comment: Python and Perl are both high level scripting language but with different philosophies.  Perl intends to let programmer do as less typing as possible, while Python forces neat structure to have easy to read code. You won't find `expression unless condition` either for same reason.

Comment: @TomFenech: I don't see how this question is related to the one you link to, which is about converting a path string

Comment: @Borodin It's not anymore! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way is to use [`sh`](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/) package.
some examples:

```
import sh
print(sh.ls("/"))

# same thing as above
from sh import ls
print(ls("/"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Read more of the `subprocess` docs. It has a lot of simplifying helper functions:

```
output = subprocess.check_output('foo', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: Also, you probably don't need `shell=True` in most cases and should avoid it for performance and security reasons in general (similarly, in Perl, it's best to avoid backticks for the same reason, in favor of solutions like 3+ arg `open` and reading the resulting file handle).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import os
print os.popen('ipconfig').read()
#'ipconfig' is an example of command
```